# JavaScript regex: Get complete JSON after (test)

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to solve a problem: I got a string like this:

```
(test){"data":{"test1":true,"test2":0,"test3":false,"test4":"","test5":""},"testarray":[{"value":"test","alt":"test-1"}]}
```

Now I need to create a regular expression that includes the complete JSON. I started this way:

`/\(test\)(\{.+?\})/gi`

https://regex101.com/r/WySywp/1

But here I only get this result:

`{"data":{"test1":true,"test2":0,"test3":false,"test4":"","test5":""}`

What can I do to get the complete JSON?

Comment: How about `.substring(6)`.  Or is this, lets use regex until our face turns blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a non-greedy modifier, so the match stops after encountering the first `}`. Just switch it to be greedy, and it'll continue matching:

```
\(test\)(\{.+\})
```

https://regex101.com/r/WySywp/2